# Spyder, Exception during debug session in variableexplorer

Tags: spyder

In Spyder I can run the script without errors:

```
filename = '$tmp$.tmp' 
# create binary file with all bytes
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(bytearray(list(range(255))))
# read bytes back
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    buffer=f.read()
print(buffer)
```

But during debugging an exception is thrown after execute the line "buffer=f.read()"

```
...
 File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\widgets\variableexplorer\utils.py", line 458, in value_to_display
    display = display[:70].rstrip()  + ' ...'

TypeError: can't concat str to bytes
```

No error during debugging occurs with:

```
buffer=bytearray(list(range(255)))
print(buffer)
```

I use conda 4.5.0, spyder 3.2.8 py36_0. For a new debugging session, the buffer variable must delete or reassigned to number, text in the console.
Exists a workaround?

Comment: one workaround: avoid a variable for the bytes. In my case its easy, in the next line of the real script the byte array is converted as float array: data = np.frombuffer(file.read(num*4), dtype='>f4', count=num)

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This is a bug. I created an issue for it [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/6942).

We'll try to fix it in our next release (Spyder 3.3).